# How to fix bug with ion-back-button?

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have implemented an ion-back-button into my toolbar in order to navigate back. But the button is not at its proper place and somehow displaced. [image: The back button in the toolbar]
I even directly copied the code from the documentation but it still doesn't work.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
```

Comment: Did you checked in Device I think it's work fine in real device.!

Comment: I solved it was actually caused by an .button{} attribute in scss